# How do I document that an input parameter is a table of some type in Lua Development Tools?

Tags: eclipse, lua, luadoc

In Lua Development Tools, how do I document that an input parameter is a table of some type?

```
mynamespace = {}

---
-- @type mynamespace.MyClass
-- @field #number var1
mynamespace.MyClass = {}

---
-- @param #number param1
-- @return #mynamespace.MyClass
function mynamespace.MyClass.new(param1)
    local self = mynamespace.MyClass
    self.var1 = param1
    return self
end


---
-- @param WHAT_DO_I_WRITE_HERE arrayOfMyClass
function processArrayOfMyClass(arrayOfMyClass)
    for i=1, #arrayOfMyClass do
        instanceOfMyClass = arrayOfMyClass[i]
        -- ... do something with an element of the array
    end
end
```

EDIT: Sorry, guys. Seems this documentation was LDT (Lua Development Tools) exclusive. I'll update my question

Comment: `-- @param arrayOfMyClass It is a table of some sort.` [docs](https://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/manual.html#tags)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that comment?

Comment: `@param <paramname> <description>`  you just describe the table. there is nothing to put between `@param` and the param name. I cannot find `#` in the luadoc reference. what effect should `#number` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `--@param #list<#bajas.ReinforcementSetup> reinforcementSetups`, works like a charm!

Found it in the LDT docs, here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/LDT/User_Area/Documentation_Language#Structure_types

```
mynamespace = {}

---
-- @type mynamespace.MyClass
-- @field #number var1
mynamespace.MyClass = {}

---
-- @param #number param1
-- @return #mynamespace.MyClass
function mynamespace.MyClass.new(param1)
    local self = mynamespace.MyClass
    self.var1 = param1
    return self
end


---
-- @param #list<#mynamespace.MyClass> arrayOfMyClass
function processArrayOfMyClass(arrayOfMyClass)
    for i=1, #arrayOfMyClass do
        instanceOfMyClass = arrayOfMyClass[i]
        -- ... do something with an element of the array
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `type(val)` to verify the type of data being passed, and return an effective error message to describe the mistake to the coder.

Comment: "How do I _document_ that an input parameter is a table of some type in Lua?" Runtime errors are not documentation.

Comment: No but it should be used in cooperation with. Documenting is easy, you should make a comment :P @oka